# Дополнительная проверка поля laravel breeze

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Использую Laravel 8 + Breeze для авторизации.

Необходим функционал ручной активации учетных записей пользователей.
Нашел в интернете несколько статей, но все они для стандартного пакета auth и для старых версии фреймворка.

Добавил в таблицу users поле "activated", пытаюсь разобраться как устроена авторизации в Breeze, для меня такая реализация оказалась очень запутанной.

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if ( ! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

Нашел использование метода  Auth::attempt в app/Http/Requests/Auth/LoginRequest.php.
Данный метод как я понял сравнивает пару логин, пароль.
Предполагаю где-то рядом необходимо так-же добавить обязательно условие **"activated" = 1**

Прошу подсказать как корректно добавить дополнительное поле для авторизации.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил функцию. Добавил проверку:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (! Auth::attempt(array_merge($this->only('email', 'password'), ['activated' => 1]), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```